# CMS Page Breadcrumbs Cache Issue

Tags: full-page-cache, breadcrumbs, holepunching, ee-1.11

I am having an issue with breadcrumbs on **Magento EE 1.11.2.0**

**The problem is:** when multiple pages are being processed by FPC the CMS page picks up breadcrumb title from another page.

**e.g.** if *http://www.domain.com/cms-page* and *http://www.domain.com/category.html* were loading together in different tabs

the CMS page will show ***Home / Category Name*** instead of ***Home / CMS Page*** breadcrumb.

If **FPC** is disabled everything works correctly. I debugged the code and the variables are picking up correct breadcrumb however when the page is rendered from cache it picks up incorrect breadcrumb.

The problem seems to lie in **FPC** but I am unable to identify the exact problem or its solution.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: bumping again since no one got a chance to review this earlier :-|

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I am having similar problems and all attempts at dynamic blocks, setting cache lifetime on the block, clearing cache settings, etc do nothing.

Comment: Yes @JonHolland I was able to fix this. I will gather and write down details as an answer in next few hours.

Comment: @JonHolland please see the answer below, and don't forget to vote it up if you found it to be useful. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had tried a lot of different things but none of them seemed to override Breadcrumbs block. It was still being cached by FPC.

So here is the solution which i implemented to fix my issues:

1. Created a new extension named CacheBust which overrides **BREADCRUMBS_BLOCK** and than modifies **getCacheKeyInfo** function
2. Added `microtime()` in `getCacheKeyInfo()` to avoid it from being cached

[Download Full Extension](https://github.com/zainsohail88/Magento_CacheBust)

Just paste the code in your app, clear Config, FPC, Block caches and its ready to be used.

Comment: Hi Zain, thanks for your efforts on this. I think I worked out the cause of the problem. I was trying to modify the breadcrumbs for the product which could be reached by more than one route and therefore the cached breadcrumb path may be incorrect. However, whilst I managed to remove the breadcrumbs from the FPC the breadcrumbs then became blank. This I diagnosed as being because the rest of the product page was cached and therefore did not call the functions to add the items to the breadcrumbs. The breadcrumbs not being independent but modified by the individual blocks e.g. category/product.

Comment: Won't this cause the block not to be Block_Cached as well? I'd prefer a solution that only causes the block not to be cached by FPC, seems like this is a way to do that: https://blog.rakshazi.cf/disable-magento-full-page-cache-for-block-6e46b1d080a8